# How to interpret a False Discovery Rate plot

Tags: r, p-value, false-positive-rate

It is the first time that I am trying to calculate the FDR and I use the `fdrtool` package in R. I want both, local and tail area graphs and I think the third subplots of [these examples](https://rpubs.com/psandovalv/3573) summarise the information. 
However, I have a rather basic question:

How can I better interpret these plots while taking into account the size of my data and the eta0 value?

I haven't managed to find any detailed interpretation of these plots, generated from this package.

Any hints will be appreciated.